# Which TD did I click on? jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table with some rows and I am using jQuery to apply a click event to the TRs

```
$("tr").click(function(e)
{
    console.log($(this).data("rowid"));
});
```

That works fine. One of the TDs, I have an actual link and when I click the link, I still get the console.log to print out. Is there a way to exit that click function if I am clicking the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `event.stopPropagation();`

```
$('td a').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This will prevent the parent `<tr>` element's click event from firing when you click on a link that's within a `<td>`.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ALUZy/

Comment: this worked great, thank you. Will accept in 5 mins when this time limit thing is up

Answer (score 2):

You should probably add a class type where your method should not be applied

Answer (score 2):

Skip any anchors:

```
$("tr").click(function(e)
{
    if (e.target.tagname.toLowerCase() == 'a') 
        return; // Do nothing.
    console.log($(this).data("rowid"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your logic to detect column clicks, and after checking the column that was clicked, execute your console.log on the row.

```
$('td').click(function(){
    if ($(this).not('a')){
        console.log($(this).closest('tr').data("rowid"));        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$("tr").each(function(t){
    if($("a", this).length == 0){
        $(this).click(function(e) {
             console.log($(this).data("rowid"));
        }
    }
});
```

To only apply that click function to table rows that do not contain anchors. If you want to still apply it to that row, except for the td with the `<a>`, use `$("td").each(...)` instead, and `$(this).parent().data("rowid"))`